# phpmyadmin mysql trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

i'm trying to write a mySQL tigger but i can't put my code in phpMyAdmin MySQL without getting a syntax error. can someone help me please?

Tables :

[image: jeu]

My trigger :

```
CREATE TRIGGER after_jeu_insert ON jeu
   AFTER INSERT
   AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @gameid int, @oldTurn int, @newTurn int
        SELECT @gameid=idpartie FROM INSERTED
        SELECT @oldturn=tour FROM partie WHERE idpartie=@gameid
        IF(@oldTurn IS NULL)
        {
            SET @newTurn = 1
        }
        ELSE
        {
            IF(@oldTurn==1)
                SET @newTurn = 2
            ELSE
                SET @newTurn = 1
        }
        UPDATE partie SET tour = @newTurn, derniercoup = NOW() WHERE idpartie = @gameid
    END
```

I don't find the error, if someone could help me it would be very nice.
Thanks

Comment: post your table definitions here http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many errors to correct.

1. No end of statements.
2. No order of syntax followed.
3. Declaration of variables is not correct.
4. Selection in to variables from a column is not correct.
5. Brace based clocks is not supported.
6. Does table `inserted` contain only one row? Otherwise you need a `where` clause or `limit`.
7. etc.

You better work more to learn.
Please refer to [***Trigger Syntax and Examples***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html) for better understanding.

Change your code as follows and it *may* work if all is well on your database objects.

```
drop trigger if exists after_jeu_insert;

delimiter //

CREATE TRIGGER after_jeu_insert after insert ON jeu for each row
BEGIN
    DECLARE _game_id int;
    DECLARE _old_turn int;
    DECLARE _new_turn int;

    -- following line may not require limit clause
    -- if used proper where condition.
    SELECT idpartie into _game_id FROM INSERTED limit 1; 

    SELECT tour into _old_turn FROM partie WHERE idpartie = _game_id;

    IF _old_turn IS NULL then
        SET _new_turn = 1;
    ELSIF _old_turn = 1 then
        SET _new_turn = 2;
    ELSE
        SET _new_turn = 1;
    END IF;

    UPDATE partie 
       SET tour = _new_turn
         , derniercoup = NOW()
     WHERE idpartie = _game_id;
END;
//

delimiter;
```